# Difference between :first-child and .children().first()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been given a Code comment to use `$('.something:first-child')` instead of `$('.something').children().first()`.
Thing is both produce different result.

Just out of curiosity, both looks to have same meaning but somehow works differently.  What is the difference between the two ?

**EDIT:** 
`$('.something>:first-child')` seems to give me the correct result, i.e. same as $('.something').children().first(), if this helps

Comment: First one is selecting first-child of  element and second one is selecting element's children first-child. Moreover the first-child works with element selector not with class selector. So, `$('.something:first-child')` is basically doing wrong... and from your edit: that works like your second code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.something:first-child')` is pointing out the first instance of element having class `.something`, where as `$('.something>:first-child')` looks at the first child of element having class `.something`.

you could have a look at css selector [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: "the first instance of element having class .something" No, that would be `.something:first`.